# How to access a stash(git) saved with `git stash save --patch name` ?

Tags: git, git-stash

I am able to `stash` a patch of changes
by doing `git stash save --patch name`
, which gets listed when I do `git stash list`.

Now how do I refer to this stash using the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stashes are named using the usual reflog syntax like `stash@{0}` etc. which is what you see in `git stash list`. There is no concept of passing name to a stash. You are probably talking about the stash message ( which, you also see in `git stash list` )and you cannot refer a stash using its message ( of course )